# border-radius style produces circles with different borders antialising on machines with different OS

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm testing my UI with Selenium ChromeDriver and ImageMagick Compare tool. I capture screenshots on pool of machines (Windows Server R2012) and compare with approved image (approved image was rendered on Windows 10). I have a couple of circles drawn with `border-radius`. Approved and actual circles borders differ. Note pixels values on flat borders.

[image: 1]

All the googling about smoothing and antialising gives me results regarding only disabling OS font smoothing, which seems like not my case (btw, I'm still disabling ClearType and font smoothing before tests run).

Why borders differ? What can be done in order to render same view?

I'm using Chrome 69.0.3497.92. I also noted OS above because it's the only obvious difference I see between runtime environments.

Image is produced by `span` with following styles.

```
min-width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border-radius: 17px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: #ce0014;
```

Comment: Do both systems have the same versions and dates of Imagemagick? Do they have the same versions of the image format delegates you used for the input image and output image, e.g. JPG, PNG, TIFF? What did you use?

Comment: @fmw42 Imagemagick versions are same. Same `compare.exe` file is checkouted from VCS when deploying on agents. I use PNG. Compare with `-metric ae -fuzz 5%`.

I don't think problem is with Imagemagick. After imagemagick comparison failed I captured these circles from browser with windows Snipping tool, zoomed it in Paint, and inspected same effect with same pixels.